# February 29 comparing to February 28 of previous year

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that pulls data and joins last year's data on the Date. The problem is that the current year data has nothing to join on because there was no February 29th in 2011. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Anyone have any ideas on how to work around it?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
--b.Date_Rep AS Date_Rep,
SUM(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedThisYearTot,
SUM(a.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedLastYearTot,   

FROM Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 b  WITH (NOLOCK) --This year    
LEFT JOIN Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 a WITH (NOLOCK) ON DATEADD(yyyy,-1,b.Date_Rep) = a.date_rep --Last year
WHERE (a.Date_Rep BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1,@StartDate) AND DATEADD(year, -1,@EndDate))
```

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` when the `WHERE` clause will force it to become an inner join? `DATEADD` can't create invalid dates, so is the issue that it *is* joining, but to the "wrong" date or what?

Comment: wouldn't this just compare it to March 1st of last year?

Comment: @J.B. I'm with J Copper - You already compare this years 28th to last year 28th so there's no date you can compare data from this years 29th to.

Comment: How do you **want** to handle it? You need to decide the business rule to follow, before you can code for it.

Comment: The issue is that the stored procedure is trying to join February 29th 2012 to a non-existing February 29, 2011. Even though there is a left join there, February 29 still doesn't show up. I tried inserting a 2/29/2011 as a blank row in the 2011 data but the system recognizes that it this date never existed and won't allow me to insert it. If I were somehow able to force the insert of that date, the issue would resolve itself.

Comment: @J.B.: No, you still haven't stated the **business rule** to be applied when comparing the two years. Also, your existing query is left joining to alias `a` and then selecting on `a.Date_rep` n the `where` clause - this effectively turns it back into an inner join.

Comment: In the interest of expediency, I simply added the 29th's numbers to the 28th's numbers. I appreciate the help everyone!

Comment: I'd be interested to learn the business reason for comparing calendar dates between years in this way with, for example, no regard to the day of the week. I can imagine cases for comparing 25 December, last day of the month, etc.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, I wouldn't do a `where` clause on columns from a table on the outer side of a left join. Try this, instead:

```
SELECT SUM(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedThisYearTot,
       SUM(a.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedLastYearTot,   
FROM Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 b  WITH (NOLOCK) --This year    
LEFT JOIN Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 a WITH (NOLOCK) 
       ON DATEADD(yyyy,-1,b.Date_Rep) = a.date_rep --Last year
WHERE b.Date_Rep BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Yes, he was converting his left join to an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` and use `COALESCE`:

`SUM(COALESCE(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear, 0)) AS AccountsCreatedThisYearTot` and
`SUM(COALESCE(a.AccountsCreatedThisYear, 0)) AS AccountsCreatedLastYearTot`

so you avoid the NULL's when the dates don't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @29Feb datetime = convert(datetime,'2012/02/29')
    declare @28Feb datetime = convert(datetime,'2012/02/28')

 select case when 
             dateadd(yy,-1,@29Feb) = dateadd(yy,-1,@28Feb)
             then 1 
             else 0 end
```

This select statement outputs 1, so actually the Feb 29 and Feb 28 dates have only one corresponding date in the past year, Feb 28.

Now you are doing a sum for two periods in different years for which it happens that the first period has 1 day less than the current period. 

How would someone answer to the following question:

```
 "How many accounts have been created in the last year's February and how many this year?"
```

Does it matter the fact one February had 28 days and the other 29? I don't believe so, the reference is February, not the days.

So I see two problems with this query:

- There might be a day this year when no accounts have been created, but in the last year, in the same period, some accounts did, so the left join doesn't catch the ones in the last year
- For this year for two different dates, 28 and 29 correspond only one day, 28 so this one is summed twice.

```
 SELECT     (SUM(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear)
    FROM Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 WITH (NOLOCK) --This year
    WHERE Date_Rep BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate ) as AccountsCreatedThisYearTot,

    (SUM(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear)
    FROM Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 WITH (NOLOCK) -- Last Year
    WHERE Date_Rep BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1,@StartDate) AND DATEADD(year, -1,@EndDate)) as AccountsCreatedLastYearTot
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no Feb 29 last year but March 1 was 365 days ago and Feb 28 was 366 days ago.

```
SELECT SUM(b.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedThisYearTot,
   SUM(a.AccountsCreatedThisYear) AS AccountsCreatedLastYearTot,   
FROM Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 b  WITH (NOLOCK) --This year    
LEFT JOIN Report2011.dbo.T_Report_01 a WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON DATEADD(dd,-365,b.Date_Rep) = a.date_rep --Last year
WHERE b.Date_Rep BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

+1 Mark Bannister as I used his syntax